# How can i execute function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am trying to make a function that returns a row based upon the number i'm giving. I have created the function but can't seem to make it work.

This is my function:

```
create or replace function vitest(t_na test.na%type)
 return sys_refcursor is t_test sys_refcursor;
begin
 open t_test for
  select * from test where na = t_na;
 return t_test;
end;
```

I have tried using:

```
select vitest(1) from dual;
```

But it gives me error: ORA-00932.
I also tried using:

```
begin
 vitest(1);
end;
```

But it says vitest is not a procedure...

How can i make it work?

Comment: Where is test.na%type and sys_refcursor defined?

Comment: @PrescottChartier: `sys_refcursor` is a standard Oracle type for a ref cursor.

Comment: I must be behind the times, I usually define a REF CURSOR Type and use it that way.  I honest to god never heard of sys_refcursor until now.

Comment: Well, it isn't a proecedure... which client are you using? Some have built-in support for showing ref cursor results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `test` table has `col1`,`col2`,`col3` columns, you could call your function as follows:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_col1   test.col1%TYPE;
  l_col2   test.col2%TYPE;
  l_col3   test.col3%TYPE;
BEGIN

  l_cursor := vitest(1);          
  LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor
    INTO  l_col1, l_col2, l_col3;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_col1 || ' | ' || l_col2 || ' | ' || l_col3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
```

*Also, your select now would change

**from**

`select * from test where na = t_na;`

**to**

`select col1,col2,col3 from test where na = t_na;`